# Overvoltage protection circuitry choice

Tags: mosfet, analog, power-electronics, protection, triac

I need to design a input overvoltage protection for a 45 W DC-DC converter rated for a 9-24 V wall wart input (so, 45W/9V = 5 A input current at max). So far I've seen two approaches (schematics below):

1. Crowbar circuit. The idea is that the TRIAC (or SCR) in case of an over-voltage will close and therefore short the input power terminals, therefore blowing the fuse and disconnecting the device.
2. MOSFET switch. In case of an overvoltage the MOSFET simply opens and the high voltage simply doesn't reach the device.

I am not sure which one should I use and I haven't found anything comparing these approaches to design the overvoltage protection. So, my questions are:

1. What are the general pros and cons of each of these circuits?
2. What are the guidelines to which circuit one should use in a particular application?
3. Which one of these should I use in my case?
4. Are there any other overvoltage protection circuits I am missing?

**UPDATE:**

In my particular situation, I am mostly trying to protect the circuitry that the DC-DC converter is powering, since it can be pretty expensive and the DC-DC converter itself. I have no idea about the typical transient voltages when the power is plugged in; mostly I am trying to protect the circuitry from an "idiot user" who might plug something over 24 V in the power inlet (I've seen up to 36V common wall warts and I am sure there are ones with even higher voltage), since the DC-DC converter is not designed for it and might output anything it wants at this point.

This is not a medical device, nobody will die if the device fails and (AFAIK) nothing could cause a fire in case of input or output overvoltage except for, maybe, potential tantalum capacitors filtering the power in the downstream circuitry which I do not control; the end user does (the DC-DC converter is for a modular synth system).

I am interested both in an answer for my particular case and in a more broad/common one showing the guidelines for selecting the method of overvoltage protection in any case.

[image: Crowbar circuit]
[image: MOSFET switch over-voltage protection]

Comment: There are pros and cons to both methods. I think it might help if you explain why you are adding over-voltage protection. What would happen if an over-voltage was applied and you didn't have protection? Would someone die as a result? Would there be a fire? Are you trying to protect downstream circuitry? What is the range of over-voltage you need to protect against?

Comment: One obvious con (or pro?) is that the crowbar will blow your fuse. What would have caused the overvoltage and what do you expect to be done as correction? Do you expect the circuit to power back normally after the fault has been removed? AFAIK PTC/Resetable fuses have limited voltage ratings, especially in the higher (few As) range.

Comment: @mkeith, kinda answered your questions by editing the post.

Comment: Consider two different kind of devices: First (crowbar solution), a device which once has seen overvoltage is not allowed to operate anymore and needs to be replaced or at least the fuse. Second (resettable overvoltage protection), a device for which frequent overvoltage does not pose a risk of degradation or the degradation is accepted (quality?).

Comment: @stowoda I am not sure that the fuse popping is the only difference between these two circiuts.

Comment: @sx107, of course not. Just wanted to point out different requirements in a general manner. If you are looking for a method to design a OV protection you should start to consider what you want to acheive. The circuit you end up with will be highly dependant on your requirements. Speed, reliability, quality, costs, etc.. How tolerant is your circuitry you want to protect e.g. towards the speed of overvoltage transients?

Comment: Protecting against overvoltage and transients are two different things. No matter which solution you go for, you should add a TVS diode. For 24V, it is common to use ~33V TVS. But in case the TVS is the only protection, it will simply burn up and short in case of constant overvoltage, so that alone might not be sufficient.

Comment: @Lundin So if I want to protect my circuit from plugging in up to 36V wall warts I should use an even higher TVS rated voltage?

Comment: Using the mosfet to open the circuit for overvoltage is used in automotive to survive load dumps. Blowing a fuse would be unacceptable in this case. Having circuitry to shunt the current would be difficult due to the time and energy of the overload so simply opening the circuit is the easiest and most effective solution, For your application, you decide what happens when overvoltage occurs. Note you don’t account for reverse voltage which is more likely. A varistor and polyfuse would be my first thought. Using scrs is old skool as mosfets would be a more modern choice for a crowbar.

Comment: Another option is buck switching power supply or an overvoltage protection IC. A zener diode will also work. Try LM2576 for 6A if you can afford the voltage drop over it.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar situation, where we had to protect ~$15 million of hardware from overvoltage. For early integration, before our custom supply with built-in OVP was available, we used a COTS bench supply.  But we wanted additional protection, especially to protect against the case that an operator might set the voltage on the supply too high.

I think we went with the Triac/short-the-supply route as just opening up the supply rail would probably have caused ringing that would have damaged the hardware anyway (these were very sensitive low power parts).

The COTs supply would protect itself against the short caused by the Triac(s) firing.  Even blowing a fuse was better than destroying the above mentioned hardware.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to over-voltage circuit protection (OVCP). An obvious one would be to limit the type of supply voltage applied by using a custom or specific connector so that only a known type of voltage can ever be applied. This may or may not be always possible. Another means is the use of some of the OVCP circuits already mentioned, however if you do not need to re-invent the wheel, then you may consider an off-the-shelf solution. There are many vendors who offer these type of OVCP ICs in a tiny package, including Texas Instruments, Kinetic Technology etc some that come to mind. Check out Kinetic Technology's portfolio of "Overvoltage and Surge Protection ICs" and you may very well find your OV protection circuit straight out of a box, with maybe even better performance and cheaper than a discreet version ...